# Django formset: {{form.instance.ide}} return record value in template but do not work in {% url 'ecrf:traitement_delete' form.instance.ide %}

Tags: django, formset

SOLED

using form.ide.value|default_if_none:0 instead of form.instance.ide
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58292564/how-to-utilise-id-field-as-url-parameter-in-formset-template-code-using-django?rq=2)

I try to implement Django formset.
I manage the basic (i.e. create and update records) but I would like to be able to delete a formset (and later add dynamically a new formset).

But to do that, I need to get access to record id (PK field is named 'ide' in my model).

But in my template, if I render {{form.instance.ide}} for each formset, it return the correct value but if I try to use it in url to set url to delete, it doesn't works as form.instance.ide return None inside url tag.

Do not understand difference between using form.ide (that do not return the value in my case) and form.instance.ide?